# Fancybox Iframe bug with internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox

I'm getting a bug with Internet Explorer. The iframe doesn't have correct size and it is displayed on the top left of the page instead of the center.

In Firefox and Chrome, everything is working perfectly.

Tried many things but I couldn't find a solution :(

Please help me.

Here's a screenshot of what it looks like:

Here's my code:

```
<head>
    <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://www.$domain/scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js\"></script>
    <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://www.$domain/scripts/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.1\"></script>
    <link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"http://www.$domain/scripts/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.1\" media=\"screen\" />

    <script type=\"text/javascript\">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.fancybox').fancybox();

            $('.fancybox').click(function() {
                $.fancybox.open({
                    href : 'iframe.html',
                    type : 'iframe',
                    padding : 5,
                    autoScale : false
                });
            });

    $(\".contactbox\").fancybox({

        openEffect : 'elastic',
        openSpeed  : 150,
        closeEffect : 'elastic',
        closeSpeed  : 150,
        closeClick : true,
        'overlayShow'    :    false,
        href : 'contact.php',
        type : 'iframe',
        padding : 5,
        autoScale : true,
        scrolling : 'no'
        frameWidth : 430,
        frameHeight : 380
    });

        });
    </script>

</head>
<body background=\"$background\" id=\"top\">

<a class=\"contactbox\" href=\"http://$domain/contact.php\">Iframe</a>
```

Comment: There are so many `\"` in this code where they shouldn't be - what are you trying to escape?

Comment: I don't know if it will actually help, but `autoScale : false` definitely caught my eye.

Comment: wow, 6 up votes... not bad for somebody trying to learn. Still I would recommend you to go back to the basics: http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp ... give special attention to the document structure and bear in mind that everything (I mean it) goes either, inside the `<head>` section or the `<body>` section. Many of your "bugs" or inconsistencies are due to your "not that good" html structure and because some declarations are outside of the sections mentioned above. Also make an effort and read the fancybox documentation, some of the options you are using are outdated. Good luck.

Comment: BTW, you either do `$('.fancybox').fancybox()` or `$('.fancybox').click(function(){$.fancybox.open({// opts })})` but not both, otherwise expect an "unexpected" fancybox behavior.

Comment: ... and BTW, you just need a single instance of jQuery (ideally the latest version). You are loading 3 different versions of jQuery (v1.3.2, v1.4.4 and v1.8.2)

Answer (score 4):

Your page is rendered in quirks mode because you don't have a correct HTML DTD declaration.

[image: F12 screenshot]

If you bring up IE dev toolbar (F12), you can see it renders correctly in standards modes.

Comment: And what would be the correct HTML DTD declaration ? I'm not familiar with that

Thanks a lot

Comment: @user1733295: I see you have some validation errors... might as well go with HTML5 :) add `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of the document before any other content